Boolean NOT is missing: the count of items in set A but not in set B is the count of items in either set less the count of items in B, right?
A computer system I'm accessing has a weird query limitation: I can query using AND and OR Boolean operators, but NOT is restricted. However, there's a way around this limitation, isn't there?
I've made a little random dataset in Excel and I'm pretty happy that A NOT B = (A OR B) - B.
But how is this shown mathematically? I haven't screwed up my Excel sheet, have I?
Here's a random example, where there are two items (members of the set?) A NOT B, eight items A OR B and six B. So $8-6=2$



Item
A?
B?
A NOT B?
A OR  B?




A
0
0
0
0


B
1
0
1
1


C
0
0
0
0


D
0
1
0
1


E
1
1
0
1


F
1
0
1
1


G
1
1
0
1


H
0
1
0
1


I
0
1
0
1


J
0
1
0
1











You have set differences so that $A-B$ is all the elements in $A$ that are not in $B$?

So what you called "A NOT B" is "A AND (NOT B)".

It's clear why this works if you draw the Venn diagram of A and B and consider the number of items in each region.

@CyclotomicField I suspect the "-" in "(A OR B) - B" may be intended to be arithmetic subtraction, while "A NOT B" may be set difference

Perhaps the point is that in "(A OR B) - B", B is a subset of A OR B, so that the cardinality of (A OR B) - B is (cardinality of (A OR B)) - (cardinality of B).

Thanks @Henry, that's what I meant, arithmetic subtraction of the number of items. The question title puts things as simply as possible, and then in the question text I think I'm not so clear on the distinction between the number of items and the actual set contents, sorry.

Thanks, @peterwhy! With a and (not b) Wolfram Alpha makes a nice truth table for me and offers notation $a ∧ ¬b$ as well.

For boolean value represented as $X\in {0,1}$, $\operatorname{NOT}X = \neg X$ can be calculated by $1-X$.

The identity you're describing can be written as
$$|A\setminus B|=|A\cup B|-|B|$$
where $A$ and $B$ are finite sets, $A\setminus B$ is the set difference (elements that are in $A$ and not in $B$), $A\cup B$ is union (all elements that are in $A$ or in $B$), and $|\cdot|$ is cardinality (number of elements).
It's clear from the Venn diagram of $A$ and $B$ that
$$|A\cup B|=|A\setminus B|+|A\cap B|+|B\setminus A|$$
and
$$|B|=|A\cap B|+|B\setminus A|$$
(where $\cap$ is intersection), and the desired identity follows by subtracting.
